# Dialing a number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dialing

I read some reference about how to make a call programmatically on the iPhone, so I put this in my code :

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:0225225657"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[app openURL:url];
```

is that correct?
If yes, how can I know that my app has dialed that number while i run this in the simulator?

Comment: Have you tried it? This seems like something that can easily be tested...

Comment: yes i tried it.. but nothing happen

Comment: Is the code even being executed? Try adding a break point or NSLog.

Comment: i've try break point it's and its' executed perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working. You just can't use it in the simulator. My reasoning is this:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[app openURL:url];
```

This is your code with but with http://www.google.com instead of your telphone URL. It opens Safari and goes to Google. Just test it on your device and it should work.

Comment: thanx guys, it works properly, nice solution.:)
i've got one more question, when i dialing the number, is this automatically close my apps as same as when i connecting to google.??

Comment: @Imam: if you have further questions, you should put a new question on Stack OVerflow.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://0225225657"];
```

??

Comment: i think that's no different between using // or no,,
just because i use the simulator, so i can't see my apps dialing that number..
thnx for the answer guys.. :)